# Python Text Files, print list with all words that begin with 'the'

Tags: python, search, text-files

I have to write code that makes a list of all the words that start with 'the' (such as there, therefore, then, the). But not have any duplicates in the list. Can anyone help? This is what I have so far.

```
def getbook():
    bookname = input("What is the name of the text file?")
    bookFile = open(bookname, 'r')
    bookString = bookFile.read()
    lowerBook = bookString.lower()
    wordList = lowerBook.split()
    return wordList

import string

def listAllThe(longString):
    theList = []
    for i in longString:
        if i == 'the':
            theList.append( i)
    return theList

def final():
    book = getbook()
    getList = listAllThe(book)
    print (getList)

final()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) datatype , it does not allow duplicates , and searching in it is O(1) (constant time).

Also, you should checkout the [`string.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) function , it will return true, if the string startswith the value passed in as parameter.

Then in your `listAllThe` function, you can initialize `theList` to a `set` using the function `set()` , and then n the if condition check like - `i.startswith('the')` .

Code with changes would look like -

```
def getbook():
    bookname = input("What is the name of the text file?")
    bookFile = open(bookname, 'r')
    bookString = bookFile.read()
    lowerBook = bookString.lower()
    wordList = lowerBook.split()
    return wordList

import string

def listAllThe(longString):
    theList = set()
    for i in longString:
        if i.startswith('the'):
            theList.add(i)
    return theList

def final():
    book = getbook()
    getList = listAllThe(book)
    print (getList)

final()
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I'm taking an into course and my professor wants us to just try things but I had no idea about the set datatype. That was really handy! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of thing that can be done handily with a Python list comprehension.  The resulting list can be used to initialize a `set`, which will remove duplicates:

```
set([x for x in bookFile.read().lower().split() if x.startswith('the')])
```